# Composite OneToOneFields in Django

Tags: django, composite-primary-key

I am fairly new to Django and I think I pretty much get the basic idea of ORM. However, there is a peculiar situation to which I do not see a plausible solution. I have a legacy database for which I am trying to write a Django app.
The sql structure of both the tables is:

```
mysql> describe event;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| cid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| signature | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| timestamp | datetime         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       | 
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> describe alerts;
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment | 
| sid            | int(11)   | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                | 
| cid            | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                | 
| confidence     | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                | 
| cvss_base      | float     | YES  |     | NULL              |                | 
| composite_conf | float     | YES  |     | NULL              |                | 
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

The first table cannot be altered because it would break a lot of code (which I have not written). The second table was written by me (hence the surrogate key).In the second ('alerts') table, (sid,cid) is  unique.

The problem is that (sid,cid) is the key on which tables can be effectively joined. How should the models be re-written so that Django can accurately capture the relation between the two tables?
I tried OnetoOne for both sid and cid separately but that is clearly not useful since OnetoOne should apply on (sid,cid) simultaneously. OnetoMany is also of no use and neither is ForeignKey since I need (sid,cid) to be the foreign key. It appears that (sid,cid) composite field should be OnetoOne but I don't know how to achieve that.

Note - (sid,cid) value will be of the type 1-55,2-55,3-55,1-56,2-57,3-60 etc. all of which are unique and will have only one entry in both the tables.

Late EDIT: I guess Django does not support Composite onetoone keys (atleast that's what one of the guys on google-group said). I migrated to SQLalchemy and it represents the model exactly as I want it (Composite keys etc)

Answer (score 0):

Django does not support composite primary key right now ( :_( i'know.. ) but its being worked on. For the time being you can declare one of `sid` or `cid` as `primarykey=True` and use [the](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) `unique_together=('sid','cid')` to enforce the composite primary key in the `event` model. Now about the `alert` model's `sid` and `cid` by default django considers `pk` of `event` model for relations, but you can use [the](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) `to_field` attribute with the `onetoone` relation to point to specific fields. so your resulting model's look like:

```
class Event(Model):
      sid = Model.IntegerField(primary_key=True,..) #primary_key = True
      cid = Model.IntegerField(...) #don't assign primary_key = True
      ....
      class Meta:
            db_table = u"event"
            unique_together = ("sid","cid") #enforces them to be unique :)

class Alert(Model):
      sid = Model.OneToOneField(Event,to_field='sid'...) #POINT! to sid of event model  
      cid = Model.OneToOneField(Event,to_field='cid'...) #POINT! to cid of event model
      ....
```

Comment: I tried this....but since many entries can have same sid (e.g. 1-55,1-56,1-57,1-58), the onetoone condition breaks. The same happens for cid. What I am specifically looking for is something tha will allow me to seamlessly join the tables.
The equivalent SQL query that comes to my mind is
SELECT alert.sid,alert.cid, event.timestamp from alert join event where alert.sid=event.sid and alert.cid=event.cid. While join through single key is accomplished by simply using onetoone or foreign key or manytoone relation (If I understand it right), how do I accomplish a join on a composite key

Comment: i'm afraid you will have to do with `foreign key` instead of `onetoone` for both `sid` and `cid`. about the join the documentation will help you  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: No that doesn't work either since sid and cid separately can have multiple values but together will have unique values. E.g. 1-1,2-1,1-2,2-2 will not work if Foreign Keys are applied separately to sid and cid. I mean the model might work, but the lookup will break the code since multiple rows may be returned (whereas foreign key requires only a single row to be returned if I understand right)